# Turning an event callback into an Async Await

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, delegates, tcpclient

I have done some thorough research and I'm not sure if I'm asking the wrong question, if my jargon is not right, it is impossible or I'm missing the obvious.

**Introduction**

I'm writing a plugin based library that creates an automated responder for a chat client (TCP Client that connects to a TCP Server (Async Callbacks for the TCP Connection))

The server returns packets based on the information requested from the client (no duh) It is currently using call backs with events and delegates for when certain packets appear.

```
var bot = new ChatClient();
bot.OnMessage += (msg) => Console.WriteLine("Message Recieved: " + msg.Content);
```

Pretty straight forward, but as I found, every single "Message Packet" is responded to by the server as to whether it went through or not, the response is a JSON payload given in the body of the packet. Currently my code to get the response looks like this:

```
bot.Message("Hello World", (resp) => { Console.WriteLine("Response: " + resp.Result); });
```

The way this works, is each message is sent out with an ID and the server responds with the Response packet with the same ID in it. I store the Action in a dictionary with that ID and then call the method once the server responds to the message.

But what I want to be able to do is something like the following:

```
var response = await bot.Message("Hello World");
```

And the response object to be the response of the message.

So if I am phrasing my question correctly, it is something like this:

**How do I end an async method with a callback from an event?**

If I am using the wrong terminology, please let me know. :) Thanks.
Ps: I'm new to this asking question thing on SO.

Comment: Note: duplicate covers case when event-based asynchronous method is only option (more similar posts https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+convert+event+to+async). Note that if library you are using is not too old it is very likely there is already existing `async` version of the same methods .

Comment: Sorry, accidentally reopened. For the modern docs, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP).